# How do you save shared preferences in a sql database?

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I am creating an app that needs to save account information for multiple accounts.   This data we want to store in an SQL database.   We also want to use the familiar, built-in shared preference code format to create and edit this data for each account.

We have created code for a shared preference with the various items for each account.

We also created the code for an SQL database that has all the same fields for each item in the preference as well as a unique, auto incremented, id field (called acct_id).   I have the various setters and getters for each field in the record... as well as the typical code for adding a record, deleting a record, and updating a record.

Both the preference screen and the sqllite helper code work... in testing... separately.

What I am not sure of is how to "load" the shared preference screen from the appropriate database record and how to "save" the changes to the appropriate database record. From what I have read on here and the internet, I "think" I need to use a preference editor... but, from what I have read, all the examples I can find are using a flat-file or XML file.   Not sure how to use those examples for the database.

Here is my preference fragment code...

```
public class PrefAcctFrag extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefacct);
    for (int i = 0; i < getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
        initSummary(getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i));
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    updatePrefSummary(sharedPreferences, findPreference(key));
}

private void initSummary(Preference p) {
    if (p instanceof PreferenceCategory) {
        PreferenceCategory pCat = (PreferenceCategory) p;
        for (int i = 0; i < pCat.getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
            initSummary(pCat.getPreference(i));
        }
    } else {
        updatePrefSummary(getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences(),p);
    }

}

private void updatePrefSummary(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, Preference p) {
    if (p==null)
        return;
    if (p instanceof ListPreference) {
        ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) p;
        p.setSummary(listPref.getEntry());
    } else if (p instanceof EditTextPreference) {
        EditTextPreference editTextPref = (EditTextPreference) p;
        if (p.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("editKey")) {
            p.setSummary("I am not going to display a password!");
        } else {
            p.setSummary(editTextPref.getText());
        }
    } else if (p instanceof MultiSelectListPreference) {
        // MultiSelectList Preference
        MultiSelectListPreference mlistPref = (MultiSelectListPreference) p;
        String summaryMListPref = "";
        String and = "";

        // Retrieve values
        Set<String> values = mlistPref.getValues();
        for (String value : values) {
            // For each value retrieve index
            int index = mlistPref.findIndexOfValue(value);
            // Retrieve entry from index
            CharSequence mEntry = index >= 0
                    && mlistPref.getEntries() != null ? mlistPref
                    .getEntries()[index] : null;
            if (mEntry != null) {
                // add summary
                summaryMListPref = summaryMListPref + and + mEntry;
                and = ";";
            }
        }
        // set summary
        mlistPref.setSummary(summaryMListPref);

    } else if (p instanceof RingtonePreference) {
        // RingtonePreference
        RingtonePreference rtPref = (RingtonePreference) p;
        String uri;
        if (rtPref != null) {
            uri = sharedPreferences.getString(rtPref.getKey(), null);
            if (uri != null) {
                Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                        getActivity(), Uri.parse(uri));
                p.setSummary(ringtone.getTitle(getActivity()));
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

As stated, that works fine as is and stores a single account in the typical preferences.   I now need to add the code to store it in the sql database.

My SQLLiteHelper looks like this...

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="MyDB";

public static final String ACCT_TABLE="acct";
public static final String ACCT_FLD_ID="id";
public static final String ACCT_FLD_TYPE="type";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ACCT="CREATE TABLE " + ACCT_TABLE + " ( "+
        "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "name TEXT, " +
        "type TEXT)";


public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ACCT);
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ACCT_TABLE);

    this.onCreate(db);
}

public void addAccount(TblAccount acct){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ACCT_FLD_NAME,acct.get_name());
    values.put(ACCT_FLD_TYPE,acct.get_type());

    db.insert(ACCT_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public TblAccount getAccount(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String SQL_STRING="SELECT * FROM "+ACCT_TABLE+" WHERE "+ACCT_FLD_ID+" = "+String.valueOf(id);
    Cursor cursor =
            db.rawQuery(SQL_STRING, null);

    TblAccount acct = new TblAccount();

    if (cursor!=null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        acct.set_id(cursor.getInt((cursor.getColumnIndex(ACCT_FLD_ID))));
                    acct.set_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ACCT_FLD_NAME)));
        acct.set_type(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ACCT_FLD_TYPE)));
                    cursor.close();
    } else {
        acct = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return acct;
}

public int updateAccount(TblAccount acct){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ACCT_FLD_NAME,acct.get_name());
    values.put(ACCT_FLD_TYPE,acct.get_type());

    int i = db.update(ACCT_TABLE, values, ACCT_FLD_ID+" = ?",new String[] { String.valueOf(acct.get_id())});
    db.close();
    return i;
}

public void deleteAccount(TblAccount acct) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.delete(ACCT_TABLE,ACCT_FLD_ID+" = ?",new String[] { String.valueOf(acct.get_id())});
    db.close();
}
}
```

So that is where I am stuck.   Any help, suggestions, or links to some sample code would be great to get me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Is it really necessary for you to duplicate the Shared Prefs data in a database?  The data is already there for you in Shared Prefs.

Comment: Yes, that was an original thought, till we realized we could potentially have well over 30 to 40 accounts.   All have the same "fields" of information but all are different.  There actually is an additional 15-20 fields that we are not showing.    We may have to do other operations on those such as searching, sorting, so a DB would be better.   Started creating a "form" to enter the info, but why "recreate the wheel" when the sharedpref capability is familiar for users.

Comment: Is that 30-40 accounts on each device?

Comment: Yes, potentially, if you have the app loaded on multiple devices and you want to use those accounts on those devices, then yes, you could have 30-40 accounts information stored on a device.